# Trigger TV alarms with If

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is there a way to trigger Tadingview alerts without going long or short. I want to close the trade at the end of the trading session. I tried that but nothing happens, no alarm is triggered

days_close_trade = input.session("1545-1600", "Zeit für Tradeabbruch", group="Tradingzeiten selektieren")
time_is_close = time("1", days_close_trade)

if time_is_close and barstate.isconfirmed
strategy.close('Close', alert_message="Entry Close {{ticker}}!")
alertLongEntry = input.string("Entry Close {{ticker}}!", "Alert Message Close Entry: ", group = "Alert Settings")

Comment: Edit your question correctly, especially for the code. Then details us what you tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.